# Locally constructible subsets of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to work through some definitions in algebraic geometry using some easy examples and I would like to have a confirmation or disproof of the following:

> The locally constructible subsets of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the open and the closed subsets.

My reasoning:

- Every subset of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ is quasi-compact, hence also retrocompact
- The constructible subsets are therefore exactly the open and closed subsets
- The same is true for the locally contructible subsets

I have skipped the reasonings in between, of course, but are the above statements correct?

Comment: You should probably add the reasoning in between, as for now this is not much of a proof. Retro-compactness is not the only important property.

Comment: @Roland The reasoning in between is based on the fact that the closed sets are the finite sets not containing $(0)$. I would just like to know if the statements are true, not if mine is a complete proof (it most certainly isn't)

Comment: Ok, yes then, the result is true for any irreducible dimension one noetherian scheme with the proof you have in mind.

Comment: @Roland Great, thanks!